# How To Access The Failed Value From Either?

Tags: flutter, dart, functional-programming, dartz

In the example below, we have:

- Type: `Either<RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract<int>, int>`
- If No Error: `right(number)`
- If Error: `left(RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract.invalidNumber(failedNumberValue: number))`

**If we need to access the failedNumberValue in (failedNumberValue: number), how would we do it?**

[Example](https://gitlab.com/ezohr_public_examples/functional_programming_examples_dart):

```dart
    @immutable
    class RangedNumberValueObjectLibrary extends ValueObjectAbstract {
      factory RangedNumberValueObjectLibrary({@required int number}) {
        var validatedNumber = RangedNumberValueValidationLibrary.validate(number: number);

        return RangedNumberValueObjectLibrary._(value: validatedNumber);
      }

      @protected
      RangedNumberValueObjectLibrary._({@required value}) : super.private(value: value);
    }
```

```dart
    @immutable
    class RangedNumberValueValidationLibrary extends ValueValidationAbstract {
      @protected
      static const _minimum = 2;
      @protected
      static const _maximum = 4;

      static Either<RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract<int>, int> validate({@required int number}) => _minimum <= number && number <= _maximum ? right(number) : left(RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract.invalidNumber(failedNumberValue: number));
    }
```

The above uses the following abstract class that uses the Freezed package.

```dart
    @freezed
    @immutable
    abstract class RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract<T> extends ValueFailuresAbstract with _$RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract<T> {
      const factory RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract.invalidNumber({@required T failedNumberValue}) = InvalidNumber<T>;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The full example with Unit Tests can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/ezohr_public_examples/functional_programming_examples_dart).

If you delve into the Unit Tests, they are performed in 2 separate ways:

> Either Unit Test using the Test Cases Framework using Left and Right results
>
> Either Unit Test using the Test Cases Framework using failedNumberValue for Left results

In the latter, the failedNumberValue is accessed as follows:

```dart
    final actual = testClass.getValue.fold(
      (l) => (l as RangedNumberValueFailuresAbstract).failedNumberValue,
      (r) => r,
    );
```